# Using stackViews in tableViewCell with custom cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistackview

[image]I have a `ViewController`.It has `tableview` on it,that `tableView` has custom `cells`.I want to hide few rows of custom cells in certain conditions.But I want the tableview to adjust the view automatically without showing any spaces left after hiding the rows.
On a simple `ViewController` this can be easily achieved by implementing stackview. But here it does no work and leaves space.I have actually taken the `label` and `textfield` inside horizontal stack view and then finally put that horizontal stack view inside a vertical stack view.
Kindly suggest the correct way to do it.Thanks in advance!

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

CustomCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    cell.label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %d",@"Label",indexPath.row+1];

    cell.textfield.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %d",@"Textfield",indexPath.row+1];
    if([cell.vertcalStack arrangedSubviews])
    {
        [cell.vertcalStack removeArrangedSubview:cell.horizontalStack];
    }
   else
   {
       [cell.vertcalStack addArrangedSubview:cell.horizontalStack];
   }
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: you need to hide whole cell ? or particular content from cell ?

Comment: If you want to hide the whole cell remove it from your data source and reload the table view.

Comment: @ HAS ..No,no idon't want to remove it...I need to hide it ,so that if user A checks that Viewcontroller then he finds all the rows but if userB checks that ViewController then he can find only even rows.

Comment: @ KKRocks...I need to hide the whole cell.

Comment: user A and user B exist at time in viewcontroller ?

Comment: @KKRocks..yes,can this be achieved through stackview?

Comment: Stackview is good option for show/hide UI element in tableviewcell.